# Cardlayout and objects?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

Hi I am doing a small project using forms. Presently I used netbeans but my classes became very complex as all jpanel ie cards  within one class which is a frame. I was asked to simplify.

My question is If I put one jpanel and it contents in one class.and make objects.
Can I use cardlayout on these objects? So that cards change within a single frame?

Comment: *"doing a small project using forms."*  My crystal ball tells me you are using Netbeans. *"Can I use cardlayout on these objects?"*  Yes.

Comment: One more related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349137/1057230)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem stems from using the NetBeans GUI editor to manage the [*top-level container*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and everything in it. Instead, use the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513) to manage multiple separate forms that can be used in your frame's layout. See also *Card Layout Actions*, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16661907/230513).